# Convert decimal to Latitude/Longitude?

Tags: c#

I am trying a GPS application and I want to convert decimal figure to Latitude/Longitude but i am not reaching on exact solution.I have tried below

```
string decimalToLatLong(decimal lat,decimal refPoint)
{
 bool isNeg = lat < 0;
        int d = (int)lat;
        int m = (int)((lat - d) * 60);
        decimal s = ((((lat - d) * 60) - m) * 60);
return (d+m+s).ToString("00.000");
 if (isLat)
            direction = isNeg ? "S" : "N";
        else
            direction = isNeg ? "W" : "E";
}
```

Comment: What values of decimal are you trying to convert? What do they represent?

Comment: What you have in latLong ? and what you are doing with your parameter `dec` ?

Comment: What values are you converting? What answer are you expecting? What answer are you getting? (Also, your conversion logic is broken. You should multiply the original decimal by 60*60 and then do modular arithmetic.)

Comment: Sample input and expected output data would be very helpful... it's a very strange request.

Comment: `d+m+s` seems very strange. What do you think it means?

Comment: decimal values are distances.

Comment: Distances from what? Without a reference point and direction, you can't translate a distance to a set of coordinates.

Comment: Decimal values are one value. Latitude-longitude are two values. That should be your first clue that something's wrong.

Comment: Yes,direction can be calculated by observing signs with input decimal figure

Comment: You can't convert a distance (1D) to a position (2D) without a) a starting point and b) a distance in the missing dimension.  It's the same as trying to convert a 2D shape into a 3D model - with only one viewpoint you can only extrude along the missing dimension, cardboard-cutout style.

Comment: starting point or reference point could be a decimal figure.

Comment: Actually looking at his code and seeing what he's trying to do, it might be reasonable to assume that by "lat/long" he means lat OR long. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Rawling: I know latitude and Longitude are each different figure but i request to consider any one of them.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : what more input data I need to solve my problem?

Comment: @Henk Holternam : d+m+s means degree + minute + second

Comment: I can see that, but simply adding them makes no sense. When is `45°30` equal to `75` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
string decimalToLatLong(decimal dec)
{
  int d = (int)dec;
  int m = (int)((dec - d) * 60);
  decimal s = ((((dec - d) * 60) - m) * 60);

  return d + "° " + m + "' " + s + "\"";
}
```

Comment: @Rawling Ah yes - missed that! Sorry!

Comment: I'd take the `Math.Round` back out - by the look of the original, I'd say he wants at least a few decimal places in the seconds value.